# Python 3d analysis (vedo): find largest spheres that can fit inside of a mesh?

Tags: python, 3d

I am using vedo to visualize and work with 3D models taken from a Lidar scan; they are .obj files that I open up.

In my application, I want to find the largest spheres the can 'fit inside' of my scanned object, if that makes sense. Imagine I have a room or hallway - basically I am trying to measure the amount of free space available.

So I want to fit in a bunch of spheres, and then see how big those spheres are. It's important that I can automate this process for whatever .obj file I load in, otherwise I would manually measure things...

Here is an example .obj file I open up, a crudely scanned hallway:

[image][image]

I'm not sure how to go about this with vedo, the closest example I found was 'Fit a Sphere' from the example website, which inspired my solution idea:
[image]
https://vedo.embl.es/#quick_start
https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo/blob/master/examples/advanced/fitspheres1.py

But then how would I define constraints on the spheres that they "fit inside" the mesh (hallway / room)?

For reference, here is my starter code, all it really does is read and display the mesh:

```
import vedo
import numpy as np

# https://vedo.embl.es/#quick_start

mesh_str = 'meshes/mesh1_indoor_scene_1.obj'

# Load a polygonal mesh, make it white and glossy:
scene = vedo.Mesh(mesh_str)
scene.c('white').lighting('glossy')

# Create two points:
p1 = vedo.Point([ 1,0,1], c='yellow')
p2 = vedo.Point([-1,0,2], c='red')
# Add colored light sources at the point positions:
l1 = vedo.Light(p1, c='yellow')
l2 = vedo.Light(p2, c='red')

# Show everything in one go:
vedo.show(scene, l1, l2, p1, p2, mesh_str, axes=True)
```

Appreciate any help, and open to thinking about other feasible solutions that can be implemented in python code.

Answer (score 1):

If you can reconstruct a surface from the point cloud you can directly use `surf.volume()` or maybe generate a grid of points and use `insidePoints()` (instead of fitting spheres), e.g.:

```py
from vedo import *
import numpy as np

surf = Mesh(dataurl+'cow.vtk').wireframe()
printc("true volume: ", surf.volume())

pts = []
step = 0.05
b = surf.bounds()
for x in np.arange(b[0], b[1], step):
    for y in np.arange(b[2], b[3], step):
        for z in np.arange(b[4], b[5], step):
            pts.append([x,y,z])
pts = np.array(pts)

ipts = surf.inside_points(pts)
printc("approx volume:", ipts.npoints*step**3)

show(surf, ipts, N=2, axes=1)
```

[image]

```
true volume:  0.8346111674784022
approx volume: 0.8287500000000002
```

You can also post an issue [here](https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo/issues).

Comment: Wow that's super cool! Thanks, this could definitely be a starting point. I was wondering - can those points be made into Spheres of a given volume, then I can count how many spheres 'fit inside' the mesh? Really appreciate the help so far. EDIT - sorry if the application is not clear; I am trying to determine how "cluttered" the inside of the room/space is. And if a person of a certain width could walk through it. Just need to make a reasonable approximation.

Comment: You're welcome, I think you don't necessarily need to use spheres, if you a have a valid definition of "inside/outside" you can use a regular set of points and just count them as in the above example. If you need to work out a polygonal mesh  from the point cloud you may have a look at `vedo/examples/advanced/recosurface.py`.